# Throwing an Error Message in Excel through comparative list Data Validation

Tags: excel, list, validation, compare

I have two sets of data which are 'list' data validated and referenced to different 'named ranges' in other worksheets in the same workbook. Some of the entries in the first list also appear in the second list. Is there any way to check if the value entered in each list in the same row is the same and throw an error message to state that they must be different?

I would prefer it if there was a non- VB/VBA route to tackling this problem. If anyone could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**VBA** is not needed.

If both columns **A** & **B** are filled by DV pull-downs, then in **C1** enter:

```
=IF(A1<>B1,"",IF(AND(A1="",B1=""),"","BAD VALUES"))
```

and copy down.

Comment: That's not quite what I was after. I wanted to avoid using a third column and just have a DV error box pop up if the two adjacent values were the same, so that a different one had to be entered.

Comment: @Kvothe  You would need a DV list that "shrinks" as an item is picked in the first column........I don't know how to do this.